# kafka-streams : to modify message structure before sending it to kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I have a scenario where I need to change the message structure which I am getting from JDBC source connector before it hits to kafka .
I am a beginner to kafka so how kafka streams can help me in achieving this .

Input -

```
{"id":"123","firstName":"pqr","lastName":"xyz","age":"23","dob":"20-09-1995"}
```

I want to store this in elasticseacrh index as

```
{"id":"123","name":{"firstName":"pqr","lastName":"xyz"},"age":"23","dob":"20-09-1995"}
```

I am not set on kafka streams, I thought to use it, if using KSQL is possible i want to know that.

Comment: Can you give an example of the structure and what you want to change it to? Are you set on using Kafka Streams, or would a solution in KSQL also be acceptable?

Comment: Input I am getting is

Comment: Input - {"id":"123","firstName":"pqr","lastName":"xyz","age":"23","dob":"20-09-1995"} I want to store this in elasticseacrh index as - {"id":"123","name":{"firstName":"pqr","lastName":"xyz"},"age":"23","dob":"20-09-1995"} No I am not set on kafka streams, I thought to use it, if using KSQL is possible i want to know that.

Comment: thanks, I've added this to the question.

Comment: KSQL doesn't yet support creating STRUCTs (which is what you're doing here), so it'd need to be Kafka Streams. I've added the tag and hopefully someone from that community can help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!!

Comment: I don't think, KSQL supports this yet...

Comment: If you are using the rest of the ELK stack with Elasticsearch, you could do this with Logstash

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Kafka Connect. For this case, "Single Message Transform" (SMT) are your friend. Those allows you to transform each message one-by-one before the connector writes the data into the topic.

Check out this blog post for more details: https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/

Comment: Using SMT is it possible to change the message structure ?

Comment: I think so: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/index.html